# CSS end of line selector to add decoration

Tags: css

lets say you have a long text

and you want to responsively (e.g. for all screen sizes) add something to before each line break.

codepen here: https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/YgWmrR

looks like this:

[image]

I want to make it look like this:

[image]

e.g.: add a caret _ at the end of each line, responsively

HTML

```
<span>
  long long text long long text text  long long text long long text text long long text long long text text long long text long long text text 
</span>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<span>
  long long text long long text text  long long text long long text text long long text long long text text long long text long long text text 
</span>
```

CSS

```
span{
  max-width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
}

br + span{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: There is no such thing as an “end of line selector” in CSS. What you want is not really possible - at least not in a dynamic/responsive way. As for not overly complicated solutions, at most I could see this somehow getting emulated by a positioned background image in combination with `box-decoration-break` maybe. But if that doesn’t work, or you need real characters to be inserted … then it is going to get a lot more complex I guess, and might have to involve JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using background and [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break).

```css
p {
  max-width: 300px;
}

p > span {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#000, #000) 
    bottom right/
    8px 1px 
    no-repeat;
  padding-right: 10px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc purus lectus, gravida in gravida non, consequat in ipsum. Aenean molestie dictum sem sed ornare. Aenean eleifend massa nunc, ut mollis mi bibendum quis. Ut at lorem lorem. Ut nisl est, scelerisque a augue at, fringilla tincidunt urna</span></p>

<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc purus lectus, gravida in gravida non, consequat in ipsum. Aenean molestie dictum sem sed ornare. Aenean eleifend massa nunc,</span></p>
```